# How to implement a dynamic chain of responsibility in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, chain-of-responsibility

I have a set of requirements on a business logic validation:

1. Each independent step of the validation must be separated;
2. The order of these steps can be defined by an administrator;
3. Steps can be disabled.
4. Each validation step isn't user-defined - i.e. the code *is* compiled.

So I thought of implementing a dynamic chain of responsibility, that'd load the steps order and classnames from a table, instantiate them with `Class.forName()`. But I'm not very fond of storing the className in a table as this could lead to potential issues (refactoring the name of a validator, for instance, would simply break the code). This is what I do:

[image]

Of course, the more flexible a solution has to be, the more complex it will be. Still, I'd like to know if there's a way to garantee the above requirements without storing the class names in a table?

Comment: well in the loading of your app you could have the provider provide the class instances to your app, where you only instantiate them from. this would do away with the forname requirement and requires you only to have a reference to the class object.

It all depends how it all is supplied to your main logic validation code.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. You could use Commons Chain from Apache as start point and mix with your custom solution. It provides an elegant and easy way to solve your problem.
   You could also save your configuration into a XML file (Catalog) and load it from you DB if you want.

Here is an example:

To see how Commons Chain works, let's start with a somewhat contrived example: the business process employed by purveyors of pre-owned vehicles (a.k.a., used car salespeople). Here are the steps that compose the sales process:

```
Get customer information
Test-drive vehicle
Negotiate sale
Arrange financing
Close sale
```

Now suppose that you wanted to model this flow using the Template Method pattern. You could create an abstract class--defining the algorithm--that looks something like this:

```
    public abstract class SellVehicleTemplate {
        public void sellVehicle() {
            getCustomerInfo();
            testDriveVehicle();
            negotiateSale();
            arrangeFinancing();
            closeSale();
        }

    public abstract void getCustomerInfo();
    public abstract void testDriveVehicle();
    public abstract void negotiateSale();
    public abstract void arrangeFinancing();
    public abstract void closeSale();   
}
```

Now let's see how you could implement this process using Commons Chain. First, download Commons Chain. You can grab the latest nightly download as a .zip or .tar file, or you can acquire the most up-to- date code by checking out the Commons Chain module from the CVS or SubVersion source repositories. Extract the archive, placing the commons-chain.jar file on your classpath.

To implement the business process using Commons Chain, implement each step in the process as a class that has a single public "do it all" method named execute(). This is a traditional usage of the Command pattern. Here's a simple implementation of the "Get customer information" step.

```
package com.jadecove.chain.sample;

import org.apache.commons.chain.Command;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;

public class GetCustomerInfo implements Command {
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Get customer info");
        ctx.put("customerName","George Burdell");
        return false;
    }
}
```

For illustration purposes, this class doesn't do much. However, it does store the customer's name in the Context. The Context object provides the glue between commands. For the time being, think of the Context as nothing more than a hash table that you can stuff values into, and pull values out of, by key. All subsequent commands can now access this data. The TestDriveVehicle, NegotiateSale, and ArrangeFinancing command classes are simple implementations that simply print out what the command would do.

```
package com.jadecove.chain.sample;

import org.apache.commons.chain.Command;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;

public class TestDriveVehicle implements Command {
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test drive the vehicle");
        return false;
    }
}

public class NegotiateSale implements Command {
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Negotiate sale");
        return false;
    }
}

public class ArrangeFinancing implements Command {
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Arrange financing");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The CloseSale implementation uses the context to extract the customer's name, set in the GetCustomerInfo command.

```
package com.jadecove.chain.sample;

import org.apache.commons.chain.Command;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;

public class CloseSale implements Command {
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Congratulations "
                  +ctx.get("customerName")
            +", you bought a new car!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can define the process as a sequence or "chain of commands."

```
package com.jadecove.chain.sample;

import org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Command;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;
import org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ContextBase;

public class SellVehicleChain extends ChainBase {
    public SellVehicleChain() {
        super();
        addCommand(new GetCustomerInfo());
        addCommand(new TestDriveVehicle());
        addCommand(new NegotiateSale());
        addCommand(new ArrangeFinancing());
        addCommand(new CloseSale());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Command process = new SellVehicleChain();
        Context ctx = new ContextBase();
        process.execute(ctx);
    }
}
```

This example shows how you can use the Commons Chain API to create and execute a sequence of commands. 
Of course, like almost every new piece of software written in Java these days, Commons Chain can be configured via an XML file. 
Applying this capability to the "sell vehicle" process, you can now define the sequence of commands in an XML file. 
The canonical name for this file is chain-config.xml.

```
<catalog>
  <chain name="sell-vehicle">
    <command   id="GetCustomerInfo"
        className="com.jadecove.chain.sample.GetCustomerInfo"/>
    <command   id="TestDriveVehicle"
        className="com.jadecove.chain.sample.TestDriveVehicle"/>
    <command   id="NegotiateSale"
        className="com.jadecove.chain.sample.NegotiateSale"/>
    <command   id="ArrangeFinancing"
        className="com.jadecove.chain.sample.ArrangeFinancing"/>
    <command   id="CloseSale"
        className="com.jadecove.chain.sample.CloseSale"/>
  </chain>
</catalog>
```

The Chain configuration file can contain multiple chain definitions grouped together into catalogs. For this example, the chain definition is defined within the default catalog. You can, in fact, have multiple named catalogs within this file, each with its own set of chains.

Now, instead of defining the sequence of commands as was done in the SellVehicleChain, you load the catalog and retrieve the named chain using classes provided by Commons Chain.

```
package com.jadecove.chain.sample;

import org.apache.commons.chain.Catalog;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Command;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;
import org.apache.commons.chain.config.ConfigParser;
import org.apache.commons.chain.impl.CatalogFactoryBase;

public class CatalogLoader {
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE = 
        "/com/jadecove/chain/sample/chain-config.xml";
    private ConfigParser parser;
    private Catalog catalog;

    public CatalogLoader() {
        parser = new ConfigParser();
    }
    public Catalog getCatalog() throws Exception {
        if (catalog == null) {

    parser.parse(this.getClass().getResource(CONFIG_FILE));     

        }
        catalog = CatalogFactoryBase.getInstance().getCatalog();
        return catalog;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CatalogLoader loader = new CatalogLoader();
        Catalog sampleCatalog = loader.getCatalog();
        Command command = sampleCatalog.getCommand("sell-vehicle");
        Context ctx = new SellVehicleContext();
        command.execute(ctx);
    }
}
```

Chain uses the Commons Digester to read and parse the configuration file. 
To use this capability, you will need to add the Commons Digester .jar file to your classpath. 
I used version 1.6 and had no problems. Digester depends on Commons Collections (I used version 3.1), 
Commons Logging (version 1.0.4), and Commons BeanUtils 1.7.0. You will need to add these .jars to your classpath, as well. 
After adding these .jar files to my classpath, the CatalogLoader successfully compiled and ran. The output is exactly like that generated by the other two tests.

Source: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/03/02/commonchains.html

Comment: interesting, I can use this Apache Commons' Chain of Responsability implementation, thanks! Sadly I think using a xml configuration file won't solve the problem, the chain order has to be user-defined...

Comment: @Tarek Couldn't you create an UI to allow users define chains order?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll do, I'm just worried about using classnames in the table. I could use an enum which would map ids to classnames, in which case ids would never be deleted, only removed from view...